# How to execute an API with multiple sets of users in parallel using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a CSV file which contains 500 users.
Set1 1-100
Set2 100-200
Set3 300-400
Set4 400-500

I need to execute an API with above 4 set of users in parallel.
One option is to create 5 thread groups with 5 files(each file with set) but this is tedious process if set increases to 20-30. Need to maintain 20-30 files.

Is there any plugin or way using which we can execute API with 4 sets of users in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why would you need 4 thread groups for this, it would be sufficient to go for a single Thread Group

If you don't need the set of users from 200 to 300 it can be removed from the original CSV file in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy code](https://groovy-lang.org/):

```
def originalLines = new File('original.csv').readLines()

def linesFrom0To200 = originalLines.take(200)

def linesfrom300To500 = originalLines.takeRight(200)

def newLines = linesFrom0To200 + linesfrom300To500

new File('new.csv').withWriter { out ->
    newLines.each { out.println it }
}
```

This code will take `original.csv`, remove lines from 201 to 299 inclusively and write the result into `new.csv` file.

You can use this file in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the "normal" Thread Group and each thread (virtual user) will take next line on each iteration

Comment: Hi Dmitri, With above option we are writing one Set(ex: 1-100 or 200-300) to new file and using it in thread group that executes single dynamic set only once. I have 100000 users each set with 10000 users(set1:1-10k,10k-20k,20k-30k,....) I need to ensure, that we use test users from each set in parallel. So that we cover samples/users in all sets irrespective of test duration. If we using one csv file with 10K users with sequential access, set-3 will be covered only after set-2. I am checking if there is any option to dynamically read rows from different sets in parallel.